# How much does a publisher charge authors if they want to make their book open access?

Tags: books, reference-request, open-access, fees

Is there any research/study/survey that looked at how much publishers charge authors if they want to make their books (textbooks or research books) open access?

I am most interested in the field of computer science, and English-speaking venues, but interested in other field and languages as well.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that publishers _ever_ charge book authors money to make their book open access? I have never heard of such an arrangement and it does not seem like something a publisher in their right mind will propose or an author in their right mind will agree to. I know this happens with journal articles but book publishing is a different world with its own quite different rules. With book publishing (of the legitimate, non-vanity variety) money will only flow from the publisher to the author (usually in not very large quantities as was recently discussed here) AFAIK.

Comment: @DanRomik personal experience.

Comment: Could that have been based on experience with a vanity publisher or predatory publisher?

Comment: @DanRomik No, happened with some renown publisher.

Comment: @DanRomik if the book's being made OA, and thus has a negligible revenue stream, if the publisher doesn't charge the author (or author's institution, funding body, etc), how exactly are they going to get the money to publish it? In practice, this doesn't happen much at the moment - but conceptually, it's no different from an OA article publishing charge...

Comment: @Andrew your "thus" is a non sequitur. Academic book publishers make much of their money from sales to libraries, and to academics who pay for books with their grants and prefer paying for a hard copy even when the book is available online for free. Many publishers these days have no problem with authors making their books open access. Personally I believe doing so may in fact be good for hard copy sales in certain cases. (Disclosure: I published a book with Cambridge University Press and am making it available to download for free, which CUP happily allowed me to do.)

Comment: @DanRomik This may vary a lot by field. My understanding is that a lot of the work towards OA mongraphs is driven heavily by the humanities, where library acquisition budgets have already collapsed to some degree, and so the revenue streams may differ from other fields. It's certainly incorrect to say that this never happens - CUP even quote a standard charge! http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/cambridge-open-access/cambridge-open-access-books/gold-oa-monographs

Comment: @DanRomik my feeling (this is not my speciality) is that in some fields you're right; a free download won't significantly limit print sales and so they'll happily set it up. But in others, it definitely would cannibalise an already limited print market. Horses for courses, I guess.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the CUP link. I didn't say that this never happens, and it's indeed interesting to discover that it does. I guess I stand corrected on my statement that "it does not seem like something a publisher in their right mind will propose". The question remains as to whether "it does not seem like something ... an author in their right mind will agree to" is also wrong.

Comment: My experience from talking to a couple of publishers (5-10 years ago, so possibly out of date) is that they were not sure what a reasonable business model would be for them when it came to open access. There were no set policies or industry-wide conventions. They were basically making it up as they went along. There wasn't anything like a standard contract for a book with open access. But I would concur with Dan Romik that it's a big danger sign if they're asking you to give them money. Don't go there. That's not normal.

Answer (score 2):

For [SpringerOpen](http://www.springeropen.com/) to publish an open access book, author fees vary according to page length, where 525 words = 1 page, and costs start about €7,000.

One option to publish a book for free would be to self-publish it using the open-source, free [Open Monograph Press](https://pkp.sfu.ca/omp/) software.

Answer (score 1):

[*The Costs of Publishing Monographs: Toward a Transparent Methodology*](http://www.sr.ithaka.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/SR_Report_Costs_Publishing_Monographs020516.pdf) was published earlier this year. It looks at the actual costs to publish rather than charges made by the publisher, but given the very limited size of the OA monograph market at the moment, this may actually be more useful. Given the relative rarity of OA monographs from mainstream publishers, it's likely that many are specifically negotiated on a case-by-case basis and general numbers are not available.

In terms of published charges, Ubiquity offer some indicative figures [here](http://www.ubiquitypress.com/site/publish/), with the caveat that they will vary in practice based on length and other issues. These are probably at the low end of the market, and a traditional publisher is likely to charge more. There are more indicative figures in [this report](http://oapen-uk.jiscebooks.org/files/2015/07/Guide-to-open-access-monograph-publishing-for-researchers-final.pdf) from OAPEN, ranging from under £3000 (Ubiquity) to above £10,000 (Palgrave).

As noted in the comments above, this will vary a lot by discipline and by the type of book - a scientific textbook and a humanities monograph are very different things with different markets, and this will influence what publishers are willing to arrange.